# "documentRef" is not a valid DocumentReference showing

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
async function process_tasks() {
    let campaignsRef = db.collection('campaigns')
    let activeRef = await campaignsRef.where('active', '==', true).select().get();
    for (campaign of activeRef.docs) {
        console.log(campaign.id);
        (CHOICE 1) let tasksRef = await campaignsRef.doc(campaign.id).collection('tasks').get();
        (CHOICE 2) let tasksRef = await campaign.collection('tasks').get();
        for(task of tasksRef.docs) {
            console.log(task.id, task.data())
        } 
    }
}
```

When I use (CHOICE 2) , **"documentRef" is not a valid DocumentReference** ERROR  show.
**There is no variable named documentRef  in my code( as a note to those comment who wrongly think so)**

I wonder why?  shouldnt `campaign` equal `campaignsRef.doc(campaign.id)`?

Comment: There is no variable `documentRef` (as mentioned in the error) in your code. Are you sure the error is coming from this code?

Comment: Where is the variable `documentRef`? Can you post the entire error?

Comment: As I understand `campaign` is a `documentRef`. I think you cannot use `.collection` on a `documentRef`. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: The error message says there's a variable named `documentRef` that is expected to be of type `DocumentReference`. The code doesn't have a variable named `documentRef`, hence my question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  May I know why do u think that my code have a variable named documentRef?

Answer (score 2):

Everything you wrote in the second election is correct, except for one thing. The variable (campaign) created in the for loop is **DocumentSnapshot**. You have to use `.ref` to access reference from **DocumentSnapshot**.

```
async function process_tasks() {
    let campaignsRef = db.collection('campaigns')
    let activeRef = await campaignsRef.where('active', '==', true).select().get();
    for (campaign of activeRef.docs) {
    //campaign is DocumentSnapshot
        console.log(campaign.id);
        (CHOICE 1) let tasksRef = await campaignsRef.doc(campaign.id).collection('tasks').get();
        (CHOICE 2) let tasksRef = await campaign.ref.collection('tasks').get(); // add .ref after campaign
        for(task of tasksRef.docs) {
            console.log(task.id, task.data())
        } 
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: so `campaign` is a DocumentSnapshot, which is a `documentref` .  We have to further use `.ref` to get the `DocumentReference`?

Comment: totally correct, you should use .ref to get DocumentReference from DocumentSnapshot. example: var documentSnapshot = db.collection("campaign"). doc(...).get();
var documentReference = documentSnapshot.ref;

Comment: you are heros in stackoverflow......   Is this documented?   I justt couldnt find in firestore documentation...